# give name of a Variable from member of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want give name of an variable from member of an array like below ... but it show's `SyntaxError: Parse error`

```
var nemads=new Array("akhaber","mafakher");
var nemads[i] = new stocks(nemads[i],urls[i],"");
```

what i can do ?

Comment: you seem to be leaving a lot out.  Are you in a loop?  what is stocks?  What line number is the error on?

Comment: you can see all of source in this link http://pastebin.com/TuYYUGbs

Comment: @thescientist what's the mistake?

Comment: where does `i` come from

Comment: it's in a loop it tht link you can see all off source ..

Comment: well, yeah now there's a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of, like this:

```
var nemads=new Array("akhaber","mafakher");
var arr = {};

for (var i = 0; i < nemads.length; ++i)
{
    arr[nemads[i]] = "test" + i;
}

for (var i in arr)
{
    var item = arr[i];

    console.log(item);
}

console.log(arr["akhaber"]);
```

Output:

```
test0
test1
test0
```

Comment: In which case in general it makes no sense for `arr` to refer to an `Array` instance, as that is the bracket property accessor syntax defined for *all* objects. (An `Array` would make sense if `arr` was implemented as a collection.) IOW, it should probably be `var arr = {};` then.

Comment: how i can refer to the my object ... like akhaber.name or other setting

Answer (score 0):

you can go with eval() method also.

```
var arr = new Array("ab", "cd");

alert(arr[0]);    //output is ab

eval("div" + arr[0] + " = new Array('12','34')"); //this created a new var named 'divab'

alert(divab); //output is 12,34
```